# Re-Use of a line fails as "`r" doesn't move the 'line-pointer' ("`b" fails as well)

Tags: powershell

As C# does not has the options of powershell's write-progress I start to try to 're-use' the same line:

```
    function ReUseFails {
        $x=0
        $nDec = 10
        while ($true) {
          $x++
          $a = $x.ToString().PadLeft($nDec)
          $z = $x.ToString().PadLeft($nDec)
          Write-Host "`r$a $z" -noNewLine 
          Start-Sleep -s 1
        }
    }
    ReUseFails
```

I expected because of `r (carriage return) to see in the same line (the next line overrides the prev.):

```
              1          1 # and after 1 Second in that line:
              2          2 # after the 2nd second
              3          3 # (and so on)
```

but what I get is

```
             1          1         2          2         3          3         4          4 ...
```

So the carriage return `r has no effect?<br>
Is there a way to 'enable' this`r??
Even when I try to use `b I see additional spots but not a back-space.
Can it be that the DOS-console can do that (to show a spinning wheel) but bot the PS-console?
Regards

Comment: Ignore ISE. It works just fine in a regular PowerShell window.

Comment: Have you considered the `Write-Progress` cmdlet?

Comment: @ Eris Yes, but I want to compile the script to a c#-exe and and c# does have a prograss-bar that can display a Head-line and status line - that's why I am looking for an alternative